# Git mailmap on bare repository

Tags: git, git-bare

I set up a .mailmap file in my git repository, so now running

```
git log --format="%aE"
```

in my local repo correctly maps all email addresses as specified in the .mailmap file.  But after I push to my bare repo and run the same command on the server, the output is unchanged (the .mailmap file is ignored).  I'm sure this is because bare repositories don't have a working tree, so the log command doesn't see the .mailmap file.  Is there some tricky way I can make it work?

The clunky way I can think of is to run:

```
git show master:.mailmap
```

and then apply some sort of find and replace operation.  Is this the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of git do you have where you are hosting your bare repository? Looking at git source, your case should be already handled by this [commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c473cecfd8835c2bdf34b323e1b2de620099c04), included in v1.8.2.

Comment: Yep, I'm on fedora which is still on 1.7.something, so I assume when I update it should just magically work.

Comment: This works. It seems like it is using the version of .mailmap in whatever HEAD points to, so you need to keep that updated if your .mailmap should change.

Answer (score 0):

The `.mailmap` is documented to be read only from the root level of a working tree, but a stray file in a bare repository also was read by accident, which has been corrected with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021).

See [commit a38cb98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a38cb9878ab686d3b7a19e46d8c3fff79cdccf4b) (10 Feb 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9bdccbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bdccbcda77df036edef5badda76418d0ae80997), 17 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`mailmap`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a38cb9878ab686d3b7a19e46d8c3fff79cdccf4b): only look for `.mailmap` in work tree
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When trying to find a `.mailmap` file, we will always look for it in the current directory.
> This makes sense in a repository with a working tree, since we'd always go to the toplevel directory at startup.
>
> But for a bare repository, it can be confusing.
>
> With an option like `--git-dir` (or `$GIT_DIR` in the environment), we don't `chdir` at all, and we'd read `.mailmap` from whatever directory you happened to be in before starting Git.
>
> (Note that `--git-dir` without specifying a working tree historically means the current directory is the root of the working tree, but most bare repositories will have `core.bare` set these days, meaning they will realize there is no working tree at all).
>
> The documentation for gitmailmap(5) says:
>
> ```
> If the file `.mailmap` exists at the toplevel of the repository[...]
> ```
>
> which likewise reinforces the notion that we are looking in the working tree.
>
> This patch prevents us from looking for such a file when we're in a bare repository.
> This does break something that used to work:
>
> ```
> cd bare.git
> git cat-file blob HEAD:.mailmap >.mailmap
> git shortlog
> ```
>
> But that was never advertised in the documentation.
> And these days we have `mailmap.blob` (which defaults to `HEAD:.mailmap`) to do the same thing in a much cleaner way.
>
> However, there's one more interesting case: we might not have a repository at all! The [`git-shortlog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a38cb9878ab686d3b7a19e46d8c3fff79cdccf4b/Documentation/git-shortlog.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog))</sup> command can be run with `git-log` output fed on its stdin, and it will apply the mailmap.
> In that case, it probably does make sense to read `.mailmap` from the current directory.
> This patch will continue to do so.
>
> That leads to one even weirder case: if you run `git-shortlog` to process stdin, the input *could* be from a different repository entirely.
> Should we respect the in-tree `.mailmap` then? Probably yes.
> Whatever the source of the input, if shortlog is running in a repository, the documentation claims that we'd read the `.mailmap` from its top-level (and of course it's reasonably likely that it *is* from the same repo, and the user just preferred to run [`git-log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a38cb9878ab686d3b7a19e46d8c3fff79cdccf4b/Documentation/git-log.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> and `git-shortlog` separately for whatever reason).
>
> The included test covers these cases, and we now document the "no repo" case explicitly.
>
> We also add a test that confirms we find a top-level "`.mailmap`" even when we start in a subdirectory of the working tree.
> This worked both before and after this commit, but we never tested it explicitly (it works because we always `chdir` to the top-level of the working tree if there is one).

`git shortlog` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a38cb9878ab686d3b7a19e46d8c3fff79cdccf4b/Documentation/git-shortlog.txt#L116-L119):

> Note that if `git shortlog` is run outside of a repository (to process
> log contents on standard input), it will look for a `.mailmap` file in
> the current directory.